# Covariance matrix is positive definite, does the variable have density?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, covariance

I know that if a random $n$-dimensional variable $Y= [Y_, ..., Y_n]^T$ has density $f$, then its covariance matrix $\Sigma $ is positive definite:  $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}: x^T \Sigma x >0$.

I wonder if the reverse implication is true.

$\Sigma>0 \ \implies Y$ has a density function.

I've tried to find such a theorem, but I failed. I do not know whether it is false or very trivial.

Could you help me with that?

It appears that this is not true for $n-$dimensional random variables in general.

Will it help if we assume that $Y$ has an $n-$dimensional normal distribution?

Comment: No -- That $\Sigma$ fails to be positive definite only means that the support of $Y$ is included in some hyperplane, in which case indeed no density exists. For an example where $\Sigma>0$ but $Y$ has no density, consider $Y=(X,ZX)^T$ where $X$ is standard normal and $Z$ is a centered sign $P(Z=+1)=P(Z=-1)=\frac12$  independent of $X$.

Comment: @Did Thank you. What happens if we assume that $Y$ has a normal distribution?

Comment: Then this is an equivalence.

Comment: @Did Could you help me prove it? In this direction $\implies $, by contradiction, we assume that $\exists a \neq 0 : a^TYa = 0$, so for $Z = a^TY$, $D^2Z = 0$, so there exists $c\in \mathbb{R}: P(Z=c)=1$, so for $A= \{y : a^ty=c\}$, we have $P(Y \in A)=1 = \int_A f dP$ (Lebesgue measure), but P(A)=0, because it is discrete, we have a contradiction, and that means that $cov Y >0$

Comment: And this was for a general random variable, I suppose that here $\Leftarrow$ we should use the fact that the distribution is normal.

Comment: "but P(A)=0, because it is discrete" No: ...but Leb$(A)=0$ because $A$ is a hyperplane.

Comment: @Did When it comes to the set $A$, it consists of those $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $a_1y_1+...+a_ny_n=c$, we have one equation, so the dimension is reduced by $1$